# Scrolling a listview with dynamically loaded images mixes images order

Tags: android, listview

In my android app I have a list of user's items.
Using a custom adapter to display them, overriding the GetView method.

From a book I got the WebImageView to lazy load images and customized it a bit.

The problem is that when I open the list view and scroll up and down, images get mixed up constantly

Here is some code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_adapterable_my_profile_item, parent, false);
        }
        iMyItemsFeedItemImage = (ImageWebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iMyItemsFeedItemImage);
        tvMyItemsFeedItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyItemsFeedItemName);


        tvMyItemsFeedItemName.setText(itemNames.get(position));


        iMyItemsFeedItemImage.setPlaceholderImage(R.drawable.images_default_product);
        iMyItemsFeedItemImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iMyItemsFeedItemImage.setImageUrl(C.API.WEB_ADDRESS + C.API.IMAGES_ITEMS_FOLDER_THUMBNAIL + itemImages.get(position));


        return convertView;

    } // End of getView
```

and the ImageWebView class:

```
public class ImageWebView extends ImageView implements OnDownloadImageListener {

    private Drawable mPlaceholder;
    private Drawable mImage;
    private Bitmap cachedBitmap;
    private boolean imageBitmapCached = false;

    public ImageWebView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ImageWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ImageWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
    }

    public void setPlaceholderImage(Drawable drawable) {
        mPlaceholder = drawable;
        if (mImage == null) {
            setImageDrawable(mPlaceholder);
        }
    }

    public void setPlaceholderImage(int resid) {
        mPlaceholder = getResources().getDrawable(resid);
        if (mImage == null) {
            setImageDrawable(mPlaceholder);
        }
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String url) {
        if (imageBitmapCached) {
            setImageBitmap(cachedBitmap);
        } else {
            new DownloadImage(this, url).execute();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadImageSuccess(Bitmap image) {
        setImageBitmap(image);
        cachedBitmap = image;
        imageBitmapCached = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadImageFailure() {

    };

} // End of Class
```

The names remain the same, in the same order that they've been initially, but the images get mixed up

Comment: @J-K Can you tell me which book you referred to for this code snippet on ImageWebView? While I faced this same problem as I'm learning Android and stumbled upon this post. I'd like to know what resource you were looking at. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember. I don't usually take code from books. Try to google samples of it to find out if something comes up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ListView is recycling views, which means that once you scroll down, the download you triggered for a list item might not apply anymore, because that same list item view has been used to display an item at the bottom of the list, which should have a different image.

What you need to do, is set the URL of the image as a tag to your ImageWebView in your setImageUrl method, and then in onImageDownloaded, check if the Url in the tag is still the same as the one you just downloaded. If it's not, it means that your ImageWebView is already being used for a new list item, and you shouldn't set the image. For that you should also add the downloaded image Url as a parameter to your onImageDownloaded method. So the complete solution is:

```
public void setImageUrl(String url) {
    setTag(url);
    if (imageBitmapCached) {
        setImageBitmap(cachedBitmap);
    } else {
        new DownloadImage(this, url).execute();
    }

}

@Override
public void onDownloadImageSuccess(Bitmap image, String url) {
    if(url.equals.((String) getTag())){
        setImageBitmap(image);
        cachedBitmap = image;
        imageBitmapCached = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I would change your entire ImageWebView class like this:

```
public class ImageWebView extends ImageView implements OnDownloadImageListener {

public ImageWebView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ImageWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ImageWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
}

public void setImageUrl(String url, int placeholderResId) {
    String oldUrl = (String) getTag();
    setTag(url);
    if (!url.equals(oldUrl)) {
        setImageResource(placeholderResId);
        new DownloadImage(this, url).execute();
    }

}

@Override
public void onDownloadImageSuccess(Bitmap image, String url) {
    if(url.equals((String) getTag())){
        setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

And in your adapter, just don't call setPlaceholderImage, simply call the new version of setImageUrl. with the placeholder resource id:

```
iMyItemsFeedItemImage.setImageUrl(C.API.WEB_ADDRESS + C.API.IMAGES_ITEMS_FOLDER_THUMBNAIL + itemImages.get(position), R.drawable.images_default_product);
```

Comment: but the method setImageUrl is in ImageWebView which is a different class, so how do I connect setTag(url) to this exact adapter?

Comment: That's the point, you don't need to do anything inside the adapter, you just need to change the methods inside your ImageWebViewClass to be like I described above. I assume DownloadImage is an AsyncTask, so just change your onDownloadImageSuccess method to also receive the url of the downloaded image, which you passed to DownloadImage in the constructor.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought setTag was some Adapter method, now I see its a View method. Will try it out right away

Comment: hm, now the images do not load. only the placeholder image is shown

Comment: @J.Kowalski I just edited my answer, can you please try with these changes?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [shutterbug](https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug) library to to display images from Url. Its easy n effective.

Comment: aside from using libraries (which I intend to learn how to do after solving this issue in my code.. Ive chosen UniversalImageLoader), is there a solution for this? what is the error in my code?

Comment: I can not say any error in your code but when listview scrolls up or down it always refresh so its sending request again to show image from URL. I have used shutterbug in my many applications and it works like charm. So try once using it.  You just need to download library add it in your project as library and then Two line code.